# How do I run a program like this in GNU-Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Every time I would try to compile it, the compilation would always seem to fail. I am very new to the language and have discovered this program while looking for examples of programs that use Prolog but I am at a loss on how to run it. The reason for using this program fragment as an example is that I would like to make a program of my own that will be able to let the user know what sickness they have based on the symptoms that the user entered.

```
domains
disease,indication = symbol.
Patient,name = string.
predicates
hypothesis(string,disease).
symptom(name,indication).
response(char).
go.
clauses
```

the program would detect an error at very first lines and I'm not sure why.

```
go :-
    write("What is the patient's name? "),
    readln(Patient),
    hypothesis(Patient,Disease),
    write(Patient,"probably has ",Disease,"."),nl.

go :-
    write("Sorry, I don't seem to be able to"),nl,
    write("diagnose the disease."),nl.

symptom(Patient,fever) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a fever (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,rash) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a rash (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,headache) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a headache (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,runny_nose) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a runny_nose (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a conjunctivitis (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,cough) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a cough (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,body_ache) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a body_ache (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,chills) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a chills (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sore_throat) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a sore_throat (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sneezing) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a sneezing (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,swollen_glands) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a swollen_glands (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,german_measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,flu) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,cough).    

hypothesis(Patient,common_cold) :-
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,chills).

hypothesis(Patient,mumps) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,swollen_glands).

hypothesis(Patient,chicken_pox) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose).

response(Reply) :-
    readchar(Reply),
    write(Reply),nl.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be TurboProlog or Visual Prolog code. Start by deleting the code starting with `domains` up to `clauses`. You will also need to replace the calls to `readchar/1` and `readln/1` predicates with calls to standard Prolog predicates such as `read/1` or `read_term/3`. In the particular case, of `readchar/1`, and only for running under GNU Prolog, you can define it as:

```
    readchar(Char) :-
        get_key(Code), char_code(Char, Code), nl.
```

Some other Prolog systems provide a `readchar` functionality but there's no standard. The main difference of these predicates compared with the standard `get_char/1` predicate is not requiring a return/enter when used at the top-level.

Also, replace all calls to `write` with arity greater then 1 with a sequence of calls to the standard `write/1` predicate and replace in those calls the double quotes with single quotes.